# img with float:left doesn't respect the container?

Tags: html, css

It happens like this:

http://img815.imageshack.us/img815/2608/senzatitolo1c.png

With this HTML:

```
<div style="border:1px solid">
   <img style="float:left"> text
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly is the question?  Did you want an explanation about why it behaves like this or a solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

add `overflow: auto` to your container to contain the image; floating pulls the element out of the flow.

Answer (score 2):

You have to clear the float at the end. (not tested)

```
<div style="border:1px solid">
   <img style="float:left;" /> text
   <div style='clear:both;'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

> **Title:**  img with float:left doesn't respect the container

By design, it's not supposed to respect the container.  As per the W3C spec, explained below, your floated element is no longer in the normal content flow.

However, here are two common methods to force the parent container to expand enough to encompass floated content within.

**Method #1** (use an empty element with the `clear` property):

```
<div style="border: 1px solid;">
   <img style="float: left;"> text
   <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

**Method #2** (use the `overflow` property on the parent of the floated element):

```
<div style="border: 1px solid; overflow: hidden;">
   <img style="float: left;"> text
</div>
```

Using method #2, in this case, it makes no difference to use `auto` or `hidden`.  Nothing will get clipped and scroll-bars will not appear since the parent is allowed to expand as needed.

---

[W3C Spec: 9 Visual formatting model, 9.5 Floats](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#floats)

> A float is a box that is shifted to the left or right on the current
>   line. The most interesting characteristic of a float (or "floated" or
>   "floating" box) is that content may flow along its side (or be
>   prohibited from doing so by the 'clear' property). Content flows down
>   the right side of a left-floated box and down the left side of a
>   right-floated box. The following is an introduction to float
>   positioning and content flow; the exact rules governing float behavior
>   are given in the description of the 'float' property.
>
> A floated box is shifted to the left or right until its outer edge
>   touches the containing block edge or the outer edge of another float.
>   If there is a line box, the outer top of the floated box is aligned
>   with the top of the current line box.
>
> If there is not enough horizontal room for the float, it is shifted
>   downward until either it fits or there are no more floats present.
>
> Since a float is not in the flow, non-positioned block boxes created
>   before and after the float box flow vertically as if the float did not
>   exist. However, the current and subsequent line boxes created next to
>   the float are shortened as necessary to make room for the margin box
>   of the float.

And here are a whole bunch of examples...

[W3C Spec: 9 Visual formatting model, 9.8 Comparison of normal flow, floats, and absolute positioning](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#comparison)

Comment: overflow: hidden, or auto as the first answer ?

Comment: @yes123, your choice... they both work the same in this situation.  Nothing will get clipped off in either case since your parent does not have specified dimensions and will simply expand.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `<div style="clear: left;"></div>` before closing div.

```
<div style="border:1px solid">
   <img style="float:left"> text

   <div style="clear: left;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add any element (most commonly seen are `br` and `div`) with `style="clear: both;"`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ensure that your floated element respect its container, you must use this type of code:

```
<div style="border:1px solid">
   <img style="float:left"> text
   <div style="clear: both"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

add float:left to the div. this will solve the problem

```
<div style="border:1px solid;float:left">
   <img style="float:left" src=""> text
</div>
```

Comment: You just told the OP to add `float:left` to the `div` which solves nothing and then posted the same code that we started with.

Comment: There is no reason to float the parent container.  Besides the fact that it totally changes the OP's original design.

Comment: What does trying it have to do with anything?  **Your solution is no good when floating the parent breaks the rest of his layout.**  In other words, your suggestion now takes the parent out of his normal content flow.